# How to protect myself against forgetting to include my "config.h"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I use a global "config.h" in my project to define various flags that enable/disable features. I defined using the convention:

```
#define ENABLE_FEATURE1    0 // feature is disabled
#define ENABLE_FEATURE2    1 // feature is enabled
```

And later in the source files I test for them:

```
#if ENABLE_FEATURE1
  // do something
#endif
#if ENABLE_FEATURE2
  // do something
#endif
```

However, it has happened a few times that I forgot to include "config.h" in a cpp file that tests for those flags. Then I get no error or warning from the preprocessor, and the program builds fine, but the compiler treats all the undefined flags as if they're set to zero, so the feature is treated as disabled in that cpp file, while it's treated as enabled in the rest of the source files.

Sometimes the consequences have not been immediately obvious even at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the following `#if` in source files.

```
#if !defined(ENABLE_FEATURE1) && !defined(ENABLE_FEATURE2)
#error "Please include <config.h>"
#endif
```

Then, you may have another problem: what if I forgot to insert the above `#ifdef`? :)

In this case, you may include `config.h` in a precompiled header (e.g., `stdafx.h`) and turn on using precompiled header. If a file doesn't include `stdafx.h`, MSVC will raise an error.

Finally, you may write a simple script to check whether every source code has `config.h`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not be the best nor the most optimum way but certainly the simplest.
Add declaration of an dummy variable in `config.h` and access the variable in the cpp file where `config.h` needs to be included.
If the header is not included it will give you compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Use some text searcher which crawls through your files. If you didn't include it, trigger a usb port which triggers this: [link](http://www.etronixmart.com/dog-training-electric-fence-system-w-one-dog-collars-p-810.html?osCsid=oclbrlneknhvf2vgad0cshpag1) :)

SCNR

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test for the definition with `#ifndef`.

```
#ifndef ENABLE_FEATURE1
    #error "someshizzle"
#endif
#if ENABLE_FEATURE1
   // do something
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Formulate config.h with a duality:

```
#define ENABLE_FEATURE1 1
#define DISABLE_FEATURE1 !ENABLE_FEATURE1
```

and then use an elif clause:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_FEATURE1
[...enabled code...]
#elif DISABLE_FEATURE1
[...disabled code...]
#else
#error "config.h is not included"
#endif
```